# Rails 4 app crashes after deployment to Heroku: uninitialized constant DeviseController (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku but keep running into the following error:

```
2014-06-01T03:06:10.404370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 42587 -e production`
2014-06-01T03:06:18.120002+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-06-01T03:06:18.120023+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:42587
2014-06-01T03:06:18.120025+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-06-01T03:06:18.120027+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-06-01T03:06:18.120028+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-06-01T03:06:18.120054+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant DeviseController (NameError)
```

My gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

#
# Twitter Bootstrap
#
gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'devise', '3.2.2'
gem 'yahoofinance' #todo: deprecate
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'simple-navigation'
gem 'angularjs-rails'
gem 'angular-ui-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'stock_quote', '>= 1.1.4'
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'redis', '~> 3.0.7'
gem 'composite_primary_keys'
gem 'oauth'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Using the ClearDB mysql add-on. I've tried restarting Heroku, running db:migrate, and playing with Devise versions but to no avail.

Comment: What does your Gemfile.lock look like?

Comment: Have you overridden the `devise/confirmations_controller`? This may explain the error, but ultimately it will likely be the case that `Devise` is not loading correctly